# How do I install an older JDK version for Android development on Fedora

Tags: java, android, fedora

I'm using fedora 24. I have `sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk`, but when building get:

```
Your version is: openjdk version "1.8.0_101" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b14, mixed mode).
The required version is: "1.7.x"
```

OK, I'll just grab that as described [here](http://openjdk.java.net/install/):

```
sudo dnf install java-1.7.0-openjdk
...
No package java-1.7.0-openjdk available.
```

I'd also prefer not to downgrade the whole system just for this. (1.) How can I install jdk 1.7 and (2.) use it just for android dev?

Comment: I can build apps with 1.8 installed, so I'm not sure what that "required version" output is coming from

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so, you can choose the JDK in the settings. You can have multiple JDKs installed, for example, I have 4 different JDKs installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This required replacing the existing jdk 1.8.0, but at least worked (getting the rpm from fedora 20, similarly to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/441757/how-install-older-openjdk-1-6-in-fedora-17)):

```
sudo dnf install java-1.7.0-openjdk java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel --releasever=20 --nogpgcheck --allowerasing
```

Figuring out the right release version was painful as google wasn't giving me anything immediately helpful with a "fedora java-1.7.0-openjdk rpm" search.

Using the [following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk) looks like you could swap between a few version, but the package manager doesn't seem to want to support this.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```